# Different drawable resources compiled

Tags: android, drawable

I had asked this before but did't get reply so I'm asking again and trying to better format title and content.

I had compiled my android app but for some reason app is showing different drawables than difined one. This doesn't appeared after changing XML code (actually I didn't changed layout code for that activity. For example in XML I have defined in imageview `@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp` but it show material speaker icon. I could also mention that I have updated and added few libraries using implementation. Removing not-used libraries and updating gradle configuration didn't fixed it. Any solution how to fix this? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not really sure what happens exactly but i think you are trying to name your

drawable resource same as android specific drawable resource name so when you app

going to be execute the priority of android specific resources are higher than

yours .

Comment: I don't think this is caused by resource's name. It happens only few times and now I updated Android Studio and I didn't captured this problem. Maybe Android Studio's problem...

Comment: as i said before : "i am not really sure" we are going to trace the issue .